# Prove $\exp \left( a - \sqrt{a^2+x^{-2}} \right) < 2 a x^2, \quad a>1, x>0$

Tags: calculus, probability, inequality

I am trying to prove the following inequality

\begin{align}
\exp \left( a - \sqrt{a^2+x^{-2}} \right) < 2 a x^2
\end{align}

where $a>1, x>0$. I cannot find any counterexample, so I think it should be ture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\exp\left(a-\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}\right)<2ax^{2}\Leftrightarrow a<\log\left(2ax^{2}\right)+\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}\Leftrightarrow0<\log^{2}\left(2ax^{2}\right)+\frac{1}{x^{2}}+2\log\left(2ax^{2}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}.$$If $x\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}}$ it's clearly true because the right term is surely positive. If $x\rightarrow0$ the right term tend to infinity because $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ dominates the other. Then your inequality is true.

Answer (score 0):

we have $e^{a-\sqrt{a^2+x^{-2}}}<2ax^2$ taking the logarithm of both sides we obtain
$a-\sqrt{a^2+x^{-2}}<\ln(ax^2)=\ln(2a)+2\ln(x)$ defining the function
$f(x)=\ln(2a)+2\ln(x)-a+\sqrt{a^2+x^{-2}}$ we have
$\lim_{a\to 1+}f(x)>0,\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $f(x)$ has a minimum with $f(x_{min})>0$

Comment: Thank you very much. I complete the proof based on your answer.